# Как заставить плеер html5 поддерживать высокие разрешения видео?

Tags: видео

Как заставить плеер html5 поддерживать высокие разрешения видео? Или такое. Допустим есть видео с разрешением 480, как мне обработать это видео скриптом так, чтобы в итоге получилось разрешение этого видео 1080 и выше(4К, 60fps)? Или у меня совсем неправильное представление получения такого высокого разрешения видео.

Answer (score 1):

Конвертировать видео в более высокое разрешение можно, но качества это не прибавит никак.

Что касается конвертирования видеофайла скриптом - почитайте мануал, скажем, ffmpeg.
Если требуется запускать конвертирование из php- ищите материалы по теме "php exec and ffmpeg"

Либо я не понял сути вопроса, что тоже возможно.